# How to get all combinations of elements ignoring a suffix?

Tags: python, performance, combinations, python-itertools

Let's say I have four elements like this

```
test = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Then I can easily get all combinations consisting of three elements like this

```
import itertools as it
list(it.combinations(test, 3))
```

which gives

```
 [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')]
```

However, now I have also several suffixes, e.g.

```
suff = ['x', 'y']
```

which I want to take into consideration. My **desired outcome** looks like this

```
[('A__x', 'B__x', 'C__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__x', 'C__y'),
 ('A__x', 'B__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'C__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'C__y'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'D__y'),
 ('A__x', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__x', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'C__y', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'C__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'C__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'C__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'C__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'C__y', 'D__y'),
 ('B__x', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('B__x', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('B__x', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('B__x', 'C__y', 'D__y'),
 ('B__y', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('B__y', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('B__y', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('B__y', 'C__y', 'D__y')]
```

So I want to find all combinations of three for both suffixes but without a duplicate in everything in front of this suffix (e.g. I don't want `('A__x', 'A__y', 'C__x')` as there would be two `A`).

I currently implement this as follows:

```
import itertools as it

def filter_elements(some_elements, connector):

    # get all elements in front of the connector
    all_elements = [eli.split(connector)[0] for eli in some_elements]

    # return True if all elements are unique
    return len(all_elements) == len(set(all_elements))

test = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

suff = ['x', 'y']

connector = '__'

test_suff = ["{}{}{}".format(eli, connector, si) for eli in test for si in suff]

all_combinations = list(it.combinations(test_suff, 3))

desired_combinations = [combi for combi in all_combinations if filter_elements(combi, connector)]
```

which gives me the desired output.

Clearly, this should not only work for four elements and 2 suffixes but for arbitrary combinations. Is there a more straightforward way of achieving this which avoids the creation of `all_combinations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you only need [`it.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> list(it.product('xy', repeat=3))
[('x', 'x', 'x'),
 ('x', 'x', 'y'),
 ('x', 'y', 'x'),
 ('x', 'y', 'y'),
 ('y', 'x', 'x'),
 ('y', 'x', 'y'),
 ('y', 'y', 'x'),
 ('y', 'y', 'y')]
```

So if you want the 32 tuples listed above:

```
list(it.product(it.combinations(test, 3), it.product(suff,repeat=3)))
```

It returns:

```
[(('A', 'B', 'C'), ('x', 'x', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('x', 'x', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('x', 'y', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('x', 'y', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('y', 'x', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('y', 'x', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('y', 'y', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('y', 'y', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('x', 'x', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('x', 'x', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('x', 'y', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('x', 'y', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('y', 'x', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('y', 'x', 'y')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('y', 'y', 'x')),
 (('A', 'B', 'D'), ('y', 'y', 'y')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'x', 'x')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'x', 'y')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'y', 'x')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'y', 'y')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'x', 'x')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'x', 'y')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'y', 'x')),
 (('A', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'y', 'y')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'x', 'x')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'x', 'y')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'y', 'x')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('x', 'y', 'y')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'x', 'x')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'x', 'y')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'y', 'x')),
 (('B', 'C', 'D'), ('y', 'y', 'y'))]
```

In order to get the desired format, you need to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
[tuple('__'.join(ls) for ls in zip(*t)) for t in it.product(it.combinations(test, 3), it.product(suff,repeat=3))]
```

It returns:

```
[('A__x', 'B__x', 'C__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__x', 'C__y'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'C__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'C__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'C__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'C__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'C__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'C__y'),
 ('A__x', 'B__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'B__y', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'B__y', 'D__y'),
 ('A__x', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__x', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__x', 'C__y', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('A__y', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('A__y', 'C__y', 'D__y'),
 ('B__x', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('B__x', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('B__x', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('B__x', 'C__y', 'D__y'),
 ('B__y', 'C__x', 'D__x'),
 ('B__y', 'C__x', 'D__y'),
 ('B__y', 'C__y', 'D__x'),
 ('B__y', 'C__y', 'D__y')]
```